# MySql Query - select data from 2 tables and replace contents of field

Tags: mysql

I am trying to finish an sql query and whilst I have found similar problems solved, I cannot get mine to work.

I have two tables, orders and cars (there are more fields but these are the ones I am having trouble with:

table_cars
------------------
ID        Title

1          Blue car 
2          Red Car
3          Green Car

table_orders
-----------------
Vehicletype

2 
2 
1 
3 
1 
2

So I have the following code, but what I need is the correct inner join syntax to replace the output of vehicle type from the ID to the title as defined in the cars table, so instead of saying '2' it will say 'red car'

Here is what I have for the select query:

```
SELECT names, phone, cprice, vehicletype FROM table_orders 
WHERE driver_id = {$UserId}
```

The results are already filtered on driver_id.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

--------------------------Continued-----------------------------------------------

Apologies, I did get it to work I was missing the 's' after the table name.You seem very smart so I am going to ask another question if that is ok.
Here is my full query so far which I know is messy! I am going to use 2 more inner joins to apply the same solution to the 'state' and 'payment' fields (can I have 3?) but my question is on the UNIXTIME fields.

The data is stored like 1384380000 in the table so I have to use the UNIXTIME with formatting to get the data to display how I want it. What I want though is the 'datetime2' field will sometimes be empty, so I want to it return either a blank field or a zero if it is empty as currently it returns a date and time like 01/01/70 01:00:00.

```
SELECT s.names, s.phone, IF(s.returntrip=0, 'No', 'Yes'), s.cprice, s.prepay, s.selpassengers, tc.title AS Vehicle, s.selinfantseats, s.selchildseats, s.selboosterseats, s.selluggage, s.selcarry, s.PickupAddr1, s.PickupAddr4, FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime1,'%d/%m/%y %T'), FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime2,'%d/%m/%y %T'), s.message, s.begin, s.end, (CASE WHEN state = '1' THEN 'Accepted' WHEN state = '-2' THEN 'Waiting'  WHEN state = '-1' THEN 'Archived' WHEN state = '0' THEN 'Rejected' ELSE 'Unknown' END) AS Status, (CASE WHEN payment = '4' THEN 'Cash to Driver' WHEN payment = '5' THEN 'Credit/Debit  Card' WHEN payment = '6' THEN 'Credit/Debit Card to Driver' WHEN payment = '7' THEN 'Account'  ELSE 'Unknown' END) AS Payment, s.driver_id FROM #__taxibooking_orders s INNER JOIN #__taxibooking_cars tc ON tc.id = s.vehicletype WHERE s.driver_id = {$UserId}
```

Thanks very much indeed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.names, s.phone, s.cprice, tc.title FROM table_orders s INNER JOIN table_cars tc ON tc.id = s.Vehicletype
WHERE s.driver_id = {$UserId}
```

I am not sure that its optimally, but you can try:

```
IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime2,'%Y') = '1970', NULL, FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime2, '%d/%m/%y %T'))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for a quick response. My query is quite complex but I was trying to simplify my question in the hope of getting an answer. I am not great with sql and have pieced together something which works for me except this inner join. Can you explain the rease for the s. and tc. in front of the field names as adding this to my query has produced an error. - Thanks

Comment: Can u write full query here?

Comment: Sorry its telling me my comment is too long and I can't answer my own question for 8 hours???

Comment: OK posting in multiple comments, not sure if that is allowed! - nope its not allowed :(

Comment: PLease find original question edited, sorry I am new to this type of forum/board!

Comment: Thanks for the response but neither are working, the fields are just blank even if they have value in them? Thanks

Comment: Can u write at least one example of datetime2 which have NULL value after formatting and have right timestamp before?

Comment: Sorry i'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you explain a little further please?

Comment: The whole field is blank with your examples, so if I have the same code as in the datetime1 field then if the datetime2 field is empty it will show 01/01/70 01:00:00 but if it has a value it will display correctly as in 16/11/13 17:00:00, but with your examples it is blank regardless of whether datetime2 contains a value